Why are these normals different between 4.1 and 4.2?
Why would normals be different between 4.1 and 4.2? This is breaking my node tree.




The reason why the normals are different is because the resulting curves from the second Mesh to Curve are different, or let's say not in the same order. I only checked the first 7 or so, but the spline with index 0 is not the same in 4.1 and 4.2 (in 4.3 it's like 4.2), the indices 1 to 6 though are the same splines in both versions.
Now if you want to know why the nodes produce the curves in a different order, I would guess some algorithm has changed, but we are no Blender developers here I cannot tell you in which way or why they changed it.
If you want to keept it consistent, you might try to sort the points in the extruded mesh before converting to curve again. You can do this with a Sort Elements node and as Sort Weight I chose the Y position of the points:

This way they are the same in both versions, note however that none of them is like the default version you had before. So since you wrote "this is breaking my node tree" I guess the actual node tree is more than what you show here - otherwise the only thing breaking here is the colors shown by the Viewer node since nothing else happens where the normals are relevant.
What I want to say is, you might be able to use this "trick" to make sure it's the same in both versions, however if the default normals are exactly what you need I do not know how to get them back in the newer version(s).

It may come from performance improvements from 4.2 but that's just a guess : https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/geometry_nodes/#performance

@Lutzi Yes, sounds plausible to me, I guess you're right. Anyway the way the question was asked the only answer for us as simple users is "because it's a new version and things are changed sometimes" :D
